# Assign item to a var with_items in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a playbook to find out on which openstack server vm is running on. I have created a list of openstack servers in vars and used delegate_to with with_items to iterate through until find vm. I am using wc -l at the end of command and 1 will be success. The aim is, once os-server is found, store servername into a var so this can be used for rest of tasks in playbook. I am unable to get the os server name in a var from the list. I am not an ansible expert. Can anyone help to achieve this? Thanks

---

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

   openstack:
     - reg1
     - reg2
     - reg3
     - reg4

  tasks:

- name: Command to find os server where vm exists
  shell: somecommand-to-check-if-vm-exist | wc -l
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ openstack }}"
  register: found_server
  retries: 1
  delay: 1
  until: found_server.stdout != "1"

- debug: var=found_server

- name: set fact
  set_fact: os-server = "{{ item.item }}"
  when: item.stdout == "1"
  with_items: "{{ found_server.results }}"
  register: var2

- name: debug var
  debug: var=var2

- debug: var=os-server
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to `retry/until` here and for the second loop as well.

Try this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    openstack: [reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4]
  tasks:
    - name: Command to find os server where vm exists
      shell: somecommand-to-check-if-vm-exist | wc -l
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ openstack }}"
      register: vm_check

    - name: set fact
      set_fact:
        os_server: "{{ (vm_check.results | selectattr('stdout','equalto','1') | list | first).item }}"

    - name: debug var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ os_server }}"
```

This will register results from every server into `vm_check.results`, and then just select elements with `stdout` set to `1`, take first element of it it (I suppose you always have one server with VM), and get `.item` of this element which contains the item of original loop (in our case it is server's name).

Comment: I m getting this error for some reasons. Am I missing anything in the above code?                   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got '('. String: {{ vm_check.results | selectattr('stdout','equalto','1') | list | first).item }}"